# Make entire page scroll when v-navigation-drawer exceeds viewport height

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

My Vuetify 2 app consists of a `v-navigation-drawer` and a `v-main` component. Whenever the content in `v-navigation-drawer` exceeds the viewport height, a vertical scrollbar appears within the component. Instead of having a local scrollbar, I would prefer the entire page to scroll when the content in the `v-navigation-drawer` area exceeds the viewport height.

Here's what my application looks like:

```
<v-app>

    <v-navigation-drawer permanent app>
        <!-- NAVIGATION DRAWER CONTENT -->
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar app>
        <!-- APP BAR CONTENT -->
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main>
        <v-container fluid>
            <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        </v-container>
    </v-main>

</v-app>
```

I have played around with the `overflow` property of `v-navigation-drawer` but was unable to achieve the desired outcome.